# How to Use RenderUI on a modular function in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

When I run this code it generates an output. All it has is a sample modular function and a main app. It works just fine but when I try to render it through renderUI it doesn't work. I know there must be a trick here I don't know of. Please let me know if you know that.

```
library(shiny)

mod_ui <- function(id){

ns<-NS(id) 

        fluidPage(
        plotOutput(ns('plot'))
    )
}

mod_server <- function(input, output, session) {
      output$plot<-renderPlot(
      plot(iris)
    )  
}

main_ui<-
    mod_ui('any_id')
    # uiOutput('any_id')


main_server<-function(input,output,session){
    callModule(mod_server,'any_id')

    # output$app<- renderUI(
        # mod_ui('any_id')  
    # )

}

shinyApp(main_ui, main_server)
```

When You twist the code a little it doesn't work. It generates a blank page.

```
library(shiny)
mod_ui <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    fluidPage(plotOutput(ns('plot')))
  }    


mod_server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot(plot(iris))
  }


main_ui <-
    # mod_ui('any_id')
    uiOutput('any_id')


main_server <- function(input, output, session) {
    callModule(mod_server, 'any_id')

    output$app <- renderUI(mod_ui('any_id'))

}

shinyApp(main_ui, main_server)
```

I am trying to find a solution to this problem so that I can create a basic Login page with conditional pages for different users. I am sure there must be something that I am missing right now but I still need any solution to this. Please at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: change `uiOutput('any_id')` to `uiOutput('app')`